Ubuntu on a MicroSD
I installed the latest Ubuntu on a MicroSD card successfully, but my MSI GP68 doesn't see any SD card when looking for bootable devices. I guess that it cannot boot from such SD card.
I wonder if there are any workarounds. Example: use a partition on my SSDs just too boot the OS on the microSD card.

Unless you get your answer here, this could be a good question to ask also on https://unix.stackexchange.com/.

Does this answer your question? Installing Ubuntu from a partition on internal drive

buy a usb sdcard adapter.

I think not. I want to avoid to use a pendrive.
The microSD is not bootable by my machine.
I guess I will try to create a boot and a boot efi partitions on another bootable drive and see if it'll work.


/boot/efi partitions can be shared.
if microSD or any drive cannot boot, one can choose an existing (or create a new) /boot/efi partition in an internal drive (HDD/SDD). Even an added /boot partition can help.
GRUB eventually gets installed there if Calamares will not let you choose where to install it.
Enjoy.

